# Language specific menu items when adding content

Tags: 7, routes, i18n-l10n, nodes

I am building a bilingual site that's English and French.  When I add a content item in English, then go to Menu Settings, click on Provide a menu link, and click on Parent Item drop down menu, I get *all* the menu items English and French.   How do I get the drop down menu item to display only English menu items if my content is in English language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No one gave me an answer, so I decided to modify the core, which is completely pathetic.  In hacking the core, I was able to add a `class="en"` or `class="fr"` to the option of a select menu.  Now I can use jquery to hide and show options as needed.  Here's a git diff of changes I made to the core system.

```
diff --git a/includes/form.inc b/includes/form.inc
index a337b03..55f705f 100644
--- a/includes/form.inc
+++ b/includes/form.inc
@@ -2564,7 +2564,14 @@ function form_select_options($element, $choices = NULL) {
       else {
         $selected = '';
       }
-      $options .= '<option value="' . check_plain($key) . '"' . $selected . '>' . check_plain($choice) . '</option>';
+       $choice_text = check_plain($choice);
+       $class=' class="opt"';
+       if(preg_match('/\{\{\w{2}\}\}/',$choice_text,$matches))
+       {
+               $class = ' class="'.preg_replace('/[^\w]/','',$matches[0]).'"';
+               $choice_text = preg_replace('/\s\{\{\w{2}\}\}/','',$choice_text);
+       }
+      $options .= '<option value="' . check_plain($key) . '"' . $selected . $class.'>' . $choice_text . '</option>';
     }
   }
   return $options;
diff --git a/modules/menu/menu.module b/modules/menu/menu.module
index fc8f68a..b991970 100644
--- a/modules/menu/menu.module
+++ b/modules/menu/menu.module
@@ -408,7 +408,7 @@ function _menu_parents_recurse($tree, $menu_name, $indent, &$options, $exclude,
       if ($data['link']['hidden']) {
         $title .= ' (' . t('disabled') . ')';
       }
-      $options[$menu_name . ':' . $data['link']['mlid']] = $title;
+      $options[$menu_name . ':' . $data['link']['mlid']] = $title.' {{'.$data['link']['language'].'}}';
       if ($data['below']) {
         _menu_parents_recurse($data['below'], $menu_name, $indent . '--', $options, $exclude, $depth_limit);
       }
diff --git a/themes/seven/seven.info b/themes/seven/seven.info
index 599879f..b625854 100644
--- a/themes/seven/seven.info
+++ b/themes/seven/seven.info
@@ -12,6 +12,7 @@ regions[page_top] = Page top
 regions[page_bottom] = Page bottom
 regions[sidebar_first] = First sidebar
 regions_hidden[] = sidebar_first
+scripts[] = lang.js

 ; Information added by drupal.org packaging script on 2011-05-25
 version = "7.2"
```

And I added a js file called /themes/seven/lang.js which toggles the options to appropriate language.

```
if (typeof jQuery == 'function'){
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('#edit-language').change(function(){
                if($(this).val() != 'und')
                {
                        $('#edit-menu-parent option').css('display','none');
                        $('#edit-menu-parent .'+$(this).val()+', #edit-menu-parent .opt').css('display','block');
                }
        });
  });
}
```

Please suggest a better way to achieve the same objective as this answer.

Comment: are you logged in as user 1?

Comment: I am logged in as an admin.  Does that count as logged in as user 1?

Comment: admin is normally user 1, you can double check if you edit your account.

Answer (score 3):

My experience is that user 1 (admin) sees all menu items no matter their language setting, but i'm not sure if it's meant to be or if it's a bug.

Better have a look at the [Issues of i18n](http://drupal.org/project/issues/i18n) and in particular at [Drupal 7 & i18n: Only current language items visible in Menu Settings / Parent menu item](http://drupal.org/node/1161184)

Answer (score 1):

After struggling on issue my solution was:

- Enable -> **Multilingual select** (module)
- Go To: **admin/config/regional/i18n/select**
- Check the *Select nodes by language*

Comment: Didn't work for me

Comment: Which part? (can you be more specific..)

Comment: I follow the instruction but I still have all the menu for every language...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Drupal's [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to filter out items that are not in the user's language or neutral.

It would be something like this:

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    global $user;

    foreach ($form['menu']['link']['parent']['#options'] as $key => $option) {
        $keyArray = explode(':', $key);
        $mid = $keyArray[1];
        $node = menu_node_get_node($mid);

        if ($node && ($node->language !== $user->language && $node->language !== 'und')) {
            unset($form['menu']['link']['parent']['#options'][$key]);
        }
    }
}
```

Terribly late answer, but probably relevant for people finding this on Google today.

Comment: You're assuming the $form has a menu attribute. What is the form id in this case?