# Both language menus show up

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

Currently I'm working on a 6-language website and all content obviously needs to be translated, including menus. For this, I have enabled i18n_menu and i18n_select (as I had a little experience on the latter regarding this issue), translated the originally French node to English, and both menu items show up when I go to English translation of the node. Any ideas?

There are several discussions on drupal.SO about this, including [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/9599/17632)  and [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/1161184) one on drupal.org; but none seemed to resolve my issue.

[image: my screenshot for the issue]

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you added the french menu item before you added additional languages to your Drupal. Then it is very likely that it was saved using LANGUAGE_NEUTRAL as language and therefore will appear within all languages.

To fix this, go to the menu's item list on admin/structure and manually edit the menu item. You should find a drop down for the language within the edit form. Make sure to choose the appropriate language here and save the item.

Comment: All the menu items say "Undefined. This menu item belongs to a node, so it will have the same language as the node and cannot be localized." for the language and I'm not allowed to change, if that's what you mean.

Comment: For further assistance, I'd like to make sure: You did enable menu translation as well within the "Edit Menu" page? Which option did you choose there? And which kind of translation do you use for your nodes? Node translation (the internationalisation module only) or entity (field) translation?

Comment: I enabled menu translation in /admin/modules, and I chose `Translate and Localize. Menu items with language will allow translations. Menu items without language will be localized.` from the menu's edit link

Comment: And for node translation? (I'm just trying to reproduce your settings.)

Comment: I have `Extended, but not displayed - All defined languages will be allowed for input, but not displayed in links.` for multilingual settings.